How to assign mutable closure to a static mut variable
I have a static variable, to store callback for some system event:
static mut CALLBACK: Option<Box<dyn FnMut()>> = None;
My goal is to be able to assign my closure to this CALLBACK (by "closure" i mean closure that really captures it's environment, and cannot be casted to 'static lifetime)
So made a struct CbGuard, that works as Guard for that CALLBACK, and guarantees it's valid state.
impl CbGuard
{
    fn new(user_cb: impl FnMut()) -> Self
    {
        unsafe{
            CALLBACK = Some(Box::new(user_cb));
        };
        CbGuard{}
    }
}
impl Drop for CbGuard
{
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe{
            CALLBACK = None;
        };
    }
}

but compiler says that user_cb must be 'static. As i understand - to match lifetimes of user_cb and CALLBACK.
But that is what im trying to avoid. I want to use it like that:
let mut my_var:i32 = 0;
let guard = CbGuard::new(||{
    my_var = 5;
});

My thoughts:

It might be reference counter as CALLBACK. But that i think it's too "heavy" for that exact problem + concept of "shared ownership" is not applicable here. Because real owner of CALLBACK is CbGuard. And he is only one at a time.
If rust has a "smart" typesystem and lifetime checks - this problem must be solvable at the language level. But i can not really find it

What might be the solution?

Of course you also need to think about thread safety.

user_cb is the same as cb? Looks like the posted code is inconsistent.

Not really on a level with Chayim Friedman here. But wouldn't it be possible change the static variable to static CALLBACK: Option<Option<Box ....>> = Some(None);? And you'd only ever change the inner Option, not requiring it to be mut?

@8192K you can't mutate the value in an option unless it is mutable

@EugeneSh. yep, it's same. Edited the code

What you think is sound is actually not. It's true that CbGuard is the "owner", metaphorically, of the callback, but CbGuard itself has a 'static lifetime, so it is possible to carry it around freely. With that, it is possible to use a non-'static closure and invoke it after it has expired.
So the compiler is right: you need 'static. Alternatively, you can make CbGuard generic over the callback type, which will prevent it from being used after its lifetime has expired (and it is possible for it to carry only a lifetime, not a whole type).

I'm attaching an example of exploit. Note that I'm ignoring thread safety here, which also is a severe problem.
static mut CALLBACK: Option<Box<dyn FnMut()>> = None;

struct CbGuard {}

impl CbGuard {
    fn new<T: FnMut()>(cb: T) -> Self {
        unsafe {
            CALLBACK = Some(std::mem::transmute::<Box<dyn FnMut() + '_>, Box<dyn FnMut()>>(Box::new(cb)));
        };
        CbGuard {}
    }
    
    fn call(&mut self) {
        unsafe { CALLBACK.as_mut().unwrap()() }
    }
}
impl Drop for CbGuard {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            CALLBACK = None;
        };
    }
}

fn exploit() -> CbGuard {
    let s = "abc".to_owned();
    let callback = || println!("{s}");
    CbGuard::new(callback)
}

fn main() {
    exploit().call();
}

Playground.

Example of a sound CbGuard, that also considers thread safety:
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::mem::transmute;
use std::sync::atomic::{AtomicBool, Ordering};

static CALLBACK_STORED: AtomicBool = AtomicBool::new(false);
static mut CALLBACK: Option<Box<dyn FnMut() + Send>> = None;

pub struct CbGuard<'a> {
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a ()>,
}

impl<'a> CbGuard<'a> {
    #[inline]
    pub fn new<T: FnMut() + Send + 'a>(cb: T) -> Result<Self, ()> {
        if CALLBACK_STORED.swap(true, Ordering::Acquire) {
            // Another callback already stored.
            return Err(());
        }
        // SAETY: We verify no other callback is stored here and locked the place, so nobody else could access it.
        unsafe {
            CALLBACK = Some(transmute::<
                Box<dyn FnMut() + Send + '_>,
                Box<dyn FnMut() + Send>,
            >(Box::new(cb)));
        };
        Ok(CbGuard {
            _marker: PhantomData,
        })
    }

    #[inline]
    pub fn call(&mut self) {
        // SAFETY: We have a callback stored and we have a mutable reference so nobody else is accessing.
        unsafe { CALLBACK.as_mut().unwrap_unchecked()() }
    }
}
impl Drop for CbGuard<'_> {
    #[inline]
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        // SAFETY: We have a mutable reference so nobody else can access.
        unsafe {
            CALLBACK = None;
        }
        CALLBACK_STORED.store(false, Ordering::Release);
    }
}


Im not really get it. What means "CbGuard itself has a 'static lifetime, so it is possible to carry it around freely"? Where i can learn more about it? also: "Alternatively, you can make CbGuard generic over the callback type". May you attach some code pls, so i can get "direction" of thoughts?

Why assigning the static CALLBACK from within a constructor is even different from doing the same from main ? It is virtually unrelated to the CbGuard struct.

@EugeneSh. The problem is that CbGuard allows unguarded access to the callback. In other words it's metaphorically its owner. But it has a capability the callback doesn't (necessarily) have: it's 'static. This can allow unsoundness.

@ChayimFriedman I am not sure I follow you. You say "callback", but I am not clear what exactly you mean. The CALLBACK or the closure itself?  Is there a single-threaded code that can demonstrate this unsoundness? Or it is only due to multithreaded considerations?

@chelovek9321 I added an example demonstration.

@EugeneSh. I added an example.

Soo. what is going on? Is the Box<..>  dropped before call ?

@EugeneSh. The Box is fine, the String the closure refers to is dropped.

@ChayimFriedman well, it's a hack. Literally reinterpret_cast. Does language have any other (not hacky) way to implement solution?

@chelovek9321 this is not a solution, but a proof your code is unsound. You cannot expose the interface you desire to safe functions.

It works, if static CALLBACK turn into None when lifetime of closure expires. I'm looking for working and 'non-hacky' code that solves that problem

@chelovek9321 As I showed this isn't sound. You have no way to reset CALLBACK when "the lifetime of the callback expires", as you said, only when the guard is dropped, and that might be too late.

@ChayimFriedman Very sad. Thanx for explanation

@chelovek9321 As I said, you can solve it by including a type or lifetime parameter in CbGuard. Whether that is good for you is up to you.

@ChayimFriedman I tried, but it wont works too. Mb i didn't catch up with your idea, so can you share code for that pls?

@chelovek9321 I included an example.

@ChayimFriedman incredible. Look like solution. Thank you!
